# Authors Suppressed Due to Excessive Length

Tags: errors, titles, lncs

How can one avoid the error message "Authors Suppressed Due to Excessive Length" using LNCS (Lecture Notes in Computer Science) template? Would it be possible to change it to First Author et al. or similar?

Comment: Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: my list of authors is too long, 10 authors

Comment: @flow Yes, we know. But if you followed the link provided by Silex, you would see that the request for MWE is legitimate. Provide a MWE giving the error, and we will try to find a solution for you. That is how this site is supposed to work in general.

Comment: @flow -- your comment is (unintentionally, I assume) hilarious.  Isn't that the error you're trying to solve?  I suspect TeX.SX will in this case grant a dispensation and allow a list of ten authors.

Comment: I have just waken up and do not get your comment jon, I will think about it today :-P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. In the preamble, do

```
\authorrunning{First Author et al.}
```

Comment: excellent, tjhanks a lot!!